# Browser is not launching through Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

While running selenium script from Jenkins browser is not launching and am getting below mentioned error.

> message="Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055;"

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: What version of Firefox? What version of Selenium?

Comment: Is Jenkins running as a windows service?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me after FF updated to v.36. Try this it is working:

1. Uninstall FF
2. Download and install FF v.33 (33<= OR >37 should work)
3. (Optional) Run: firefox.exe -p  to delete profile with files. Close Profile Manager
4. (Optional) Open FF. Do not import anything from different browsers
5. Run your tests